# Elasticsearch percentiles overflow

Tags: elasticsearch, overflow

I'm running an elasticsearch query (ancient version 2.3.3) to grab percentiles.  The data set contains a little over 2 billion records and my query sometimes returns the expected values and other times returns numbers like 4.329432183e+16 for all the percentiles.

The field I'm grabbing percentiles for does not have any values above 10,000,000 and the query looks something like

```
{
   "aggregations" : {
      "percentile" : {
         "percentiles" : {
            "field" : "myfield",
            "percents" : [
               "10",
               "50",
               "90",
               "95",
               "99"
            ]
         }
      },
      "total" : {
         "sum" : {
            "field" : "myfield"
         }
      }
   },
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : {
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
               "must" : [
                  {
                     "range" : {
                        "otherfield1" : {
                           "gte" : "0",
                           "lt" : "100"
                        }
                     }
                  },
               ],
               "must_not" : [
                  {
                     "term" : {
                        "otherfield2" : true
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Why does the query occasionally return results like 4.324184324e+16 and other times returns expected results in the range of ~10 to ~100,000?

Is there a better way to construct this query to avoid those 4.123842134e+16 numbers from being returned?

Answer (score 0):

There's too little info to truly debug this but you can try to add a `range` on `myfield` which should guarantee values in a given interval:

```json
{
  "aggregations": {
    "percentile": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "myfield",
        "percents": [
          "10",
          "50",
          "90",
          "95",
          "99"
        ]
      }
    },
    "total": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "myfield"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "myfield": {
                  "gte": 0,
                  "lte": 10000000        <--- add this
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "otherfield1": {
                  "gte": "0",
                  "lt": "100"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "otherfield2": true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, modifying the query so that the calculation is performed against a smaller dataset does work.  I think the general question is "why are percentile calculations so obviously wrong when using large datasets?"

Anyways, I can't just lop off part of the dataset.  I ended up switching the percentile calculation from the built in t-digest algorithm to HDR Histogram.  The calculations from the HDR Histogram were within the expected range.  Not sure if HDR Histogram is better with large datasets in general or if it's just better with the particular distribution of my data points